# What is Naive Bayes properties: useKernelEstimator and useSupervisedDiscretization

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, weka, naivebayes

I am using Naive Bayes as the learning algorithm in Weka data mining tool. There are parameter options in Naive Bayes as 'useKernelEstimator' and 'useSupervisedDiscretization'. Can someone plese tell me what these two parameters are? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a pro in kernelEstimator. To understand the last two. you have to understand the first two concepts first.

> **KernelEstimator**: the precision to which numeric values are given. For example, if the precision is stated to be 0.1, the values in the interval (0.25,0.35] are all treated as 0.3.
>
> **Supervised Discretization** Once in a while one has numeric data but wants to use classifier that handles only nominal values. In that case one needs to discretize the data
>
> **useKernelEstimator** -- Use a kernel estimator for numeric attributes rather than a normal distribution.
>
> **useSupervisedDiscretization** -- Use supervised discretization to convert numeric attributes to nominal ones.

Comment: @NikolayKostove Can you please exaplain the two concepts in a bit simpler way? :)

Comment: Can you please exaplain the two concepts in a bit simpler way? :)